Do optimal Lieb-Thirring constants have physical meaning?
In their proof of stability of matter Lieb and Thirring used a particular set of inequalities. Namely, if $H=-\Delta+V(x)$ is a Schrödinger operator, then the sum of (powers of the absolute value of) the corresponding negative eigenvalues is bounded by the integral of the negative part of the potential. Namely, in dimension $d\geq 2$ and $\gamma>0$ there exists a constant $L_{\gamma, d}$ such that
$$ \sum_{\lambda \in \mathrm{spec}(H) \cap (-\infty,0)} \vert \lambda \vert^\gamma \leq L_{\gamma, d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} V_-(x)^{\gamma+d/2} dx $$
where $V_-(x)=\max\{ 0, -V(x)\}$.
In the past decades mathematicians have spend a lot of effort to determine the optimal constant $L_{\gamma, d}$. This leads to my question:

Is this constant of any physical relevance?

I am aware of connections to other optimal constants within mathematics, but it is not quite clear to me whether this optimal Lieb-Thirring constant is supposed to give any physical insight.
Added: At the end of the day, the goal was to show stability of matter of the second kind. Namely, if one considers an atomic Hamiltonian $H_{N,K}$ with $N$ electrons and $K$ nuclei, then the ground state energy $E_{N,K}$ is bounded from below as
$$ E_{N,K} \geq - C(N+K). $$
Of course the Lieb-Thirring constant will enter in $C$, but the improvements of those constants are fairly small (they have the same order of magnitude).

Can you find a class of potentials for which it is minimal, i.e. not exhausting the bound?

@FlatterMann The optimal constant is not really known (with very few exceptions, like $d=1, \gamma=1/2$). I don't know whether there is a reasonable class of functions for which one can compute the optimal constant. What made me ask this question is that so much energy is spend on the mathematical physics side to get even (perceived) very small improvements (like here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05069). Thus, I wondered whether this constant represents something that I am not aware of.

Sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't mean a potential that exhausts the bound but a potential that is way, way below. Like... what are typical values for e.g. a box potential or a harmonic oscillator? If it turns out that we have to construct extremely unphysical potentials (like white noise or self-similar functions for V(x)) to get anywhere close to the max. then this is probably more of a mathematical curiosity.

@FlatterMann Sorry, I've misread your question. The harmonic oscillator gives you no negative eigenvalues, hence, zero on the LHS and infinity on the RHS (and no reasonable constant is going to fix this). For reasonable physical potential (box potentials, Coulmb) you get something of the right order and the inequality scales the right way.

And there is your answer: it doesn't tell you much, at all. The harmonic oscillator, box potentials and Coulomb are all physically meaningful, but the behavior of this inequality is all over the place.

@FlatterMann I don't see how this inequalitity is all over the place. Especially, the harmonic oscillator is not really relevant as we are looking at atomic Hamiltonians. Sometimes the constant actually reflects something inherently physical (for example for the ionization conjecture where the constant measure the number of electrons which can be bound by atoms). I am just asking whether the Lieb-Thirring constant can be interpreted as something like that.

I don't know what you mean by "the harmonic oscillator is not relevant". Take a good look at the difference between the Coulomb potential and the harmonic oscillator and a box. What has changed, really? The Coulomb potential is infinitely deep. Does that make any physical sense? No, of course not. The charge distribution inside a nucleus is NOT like that. It becomes almost constant. The real (mean field theoretical) physical potential is very different from the theoretical model. You are looking at a mathematical formula that is sensitive to an artifact of an approximation.

@FlatterMann I've made a mistake in my previous comment. Namely, I've forgotten to take the negative part of the harmonic oscillator, which renders the integral zero (and therefore equal to the LHS).

That's not helpful, either. A formula that is independent of physics can't tell us anything about it.

@FlatterMann This inequality quantifies the number of bound states in terms of the phase space volume (i.e. semiclassical approximation if you wish). It also yields the linear lower bound in terms of number of nucleii and electrons on the ground state energy of the atomic Hamiltonian.  Saying that the inequality has no physical meaning seems unjustified to me.

If it gives you the same number for multiple potentials, then it can't differentiate between them. I don't know what "the lower bound of electrons and nuclei on the ground state of the Hamiltonian" is supposed to mean.
